# Spring boot webjars not generated, Http 406 returned

Tags: java, spring-boot, webjars, spring-boot-configuration

For some reason bootstrap webjars are not being copied into target, and for that reason they cannot be found.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

...

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Resource handlers:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/*");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
}
```

Somewhere in my static `resources`

```
...
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
```

[image]

Nothing is generated into `/target`
Any idea what am I missing?
I spend few hours on this and also reached second page on google searches.

Comment: That all seems like it should work.  But it isn't quite consistent with what you need to do for Spring Boot.  Check out: https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springboot

Comment: @JamesWard I double checked with the linked you sent. Results are exactly the same. I also changed into `version agnostic` approach with new dependency, however it does exactly the same.
What you mean by saying its not consistent?

Comment: Remove the `WebConfiguration`, Spring Boot already takes care of all that and you are basically disabling parts of Spring Boot pautoconfiguration with that config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

I would never tell that could be a problem but apparently `@GetMapping` annotation broke my UI. I still didn't figure it out what was the problem. I just found solution.

So I used `Thymelea`f to resolve my views

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "/home";
    }
}
```

And apparently it clashes when I use traditional Restful controller

```
@RestController(value = "/face-detection")
public class FaceDetectController {

@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) {
...
```

This single `@GetMapping` was breaking entire UI.
What I had to do was simply add `/` in the mapping

```
@GetMapping(value ="/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

And the whole thing magically started to work.
Similar issue somewhere deep in the github:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1647